# MySQL set maximum value to 9999

Tags: mysql

How to set Maximum int value to 9999

table structure:

```
ID  ---INT
Num ---INT should not get more then 9999 value
```

is it possible on mysql.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use MySQL CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Comment: Besides using a `CONSTRAINT` on the DB side, you could also implement business logic on the server side to prevent `UPDATE`s with `Num` >= 10000 from taking place.

Answer (score 1):

You can set maximum value of a column by creating a trigger. Just create a trigger which checks the value to be less than 9999. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF columnName > 9999 THEN
    CALL `Error: Cannot insert this value`; 
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: there are many other trigger on my database, can not use more it will slow down the execution of queries

Comment: Using a trigger is really your only option as MySQL does **not** support check constraints.